# Operations on normal IID.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

Suppose $X_1,X_2\stackrel{iid}{\sim} N(0,1)$. We define $Y_1:=X_1+X_2$ and $Y_2:=X_1-X_2$. Then

a) Show that $Y_1,Y_2\stackrel{iid}{\sim}N(0,2)$.

b) Compute the distribution of $Y_1$ directly using the convolution formula

c) Find distribution of $Z:=\frac{X_1}{X_2}$

d) Does $Z:=\frac{X_1}{X_2}$ have finite mean?

The question is a part of my homework I have solved part a and b but I am stuck at the part for ratio ditribution this is what I thought of:
$$\frac{X_1}{X_2}=\frac{1}{4}\left(X_1+\frac{1}{X_2}\right)^2-\frac{1}{4}\left(X_1-\frac{1}{X_2}\right)^2$$

So if I am able to express $\frac{1}{X_2}$ as a normal ditribution then we can find the ditribution of $Z$, as sum,difference and product of two normal distributions are also a normal ditribution it feels like same sholud be for quotient, but I am not sure if it is true.I missed the class when the professor explained this so I was hoping that I could understand it through this problem.Please help me with this any kind of help is appericated.

Comment: This is [solved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution#Uncorrelated_central_normal_ratio).

Comment: You can use the change of density formula with the bijection $(x_1, x_2) \to (x_2/x_1, x_1).$